# How to debug installed Ruby gems inside Docker?

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, bundler

I understand how to debug my app files using byebug and pry. However I often need to debug gems installed **inside a container** and I don't like the option of running shell inside docker, then installing smth like nano (if it's not already installed) and changing the gem files to add breakpoints. I know RubyMine solved it already. Maybe there is a way for others as well? (I'm using Sublime Text).

Comment: For similar scenarios, I always mount the folder in question (in your case, the gems folder) and then I work and edit the files locally with Sublime (of course, copy what is needed to the mounted volume if not already there).